# Click same elements query

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hay

mi problem is this code click 1 element nod all

hello all my problem is that this code presses on the first one (SendResurces) and on the others not how to fix it thank everyone for the help

(example in the code there are maybe 50 clicks on Send Resurces) and this code clicks on the first (and next nod click)

```
javascript: setTimeout(function() {     document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Send resources']")[0].click();    }, (Math.random() * 200) + 500);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you should rephrase your question, since I'm having problems to understand your problem.
The provided code looks like it triggers a click event on the first element matching the given selector after 500+x ms. When you write "nod" do you mean not or node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ok:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var arr = $("input[value='Send resources']");
  var i = 0;

  var t = setInterval(function() {
    if (i > arr.length) {
      clearInterval(t);
    }
    $(arr[i++]).click();
  }, 200 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
})();
```

Comment: Change `$(arr[i++]).click();` to `arr.eq(i++).click()` to avoid the unnecessary use of jQuery to wrap an object twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Send 
resources']");

inputs.forEach( (input, index) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
       input.click();
    },(Math.random() * 200) + 500);
});
```